Trying to display the top 10 trends
I've created an app in x developer and i got my bearer token, API key, API key secret, access token and access token secret, client id and client secret. However when I execute my code i am getting a 403 forbidden error which twitter says it means

The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why.Check that your developer account includes access to the endpoint you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted (e.g. Engagement API or Ads API) or sign up for access.".

I have the free access on x developer
this is my code:
aspx:
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="twitter_trends.aspx.vb" Inherits="twitter_trends" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Twitter Trends</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Top 10 Twitter Trends</h1>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptTrends" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p><strong><%# Eval("trend_name") %></strong> - Tweets: <%# Eval("tweet_count") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

vb:
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Partial Class twitter_trends
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' Ensure your application uses TLS 1.2 or higher
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        ' Call the function to get the trends
        Dim trends As String = GetTwitterTrends()

        ' Display the result (or handle it appropriately)
        Response.Write(trends)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTwitterTrends() As String
        ' Replace with your actual bearer token and WOEID
        Dim bearerToken As String = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMnKvwEAAAAAimlqPsahop8IlT95p1flZ8eI818%3DDKparMoGqpc31rlBg07SsPmw2soeXqBcH325SYsqxi5FAhjkBv"
        Dim woeid As String = "1" ' Use 1 for global trends or specify a location

        ' Create the request
        Dim url As String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=" & woeid
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & bearerToken)
        request.ContentType = "application/json"

        Try
            ' Get the response
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim jsonResponse As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Return jsonResponse
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Handle any errors
            Return "Error: " & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
End Class

can anyone help ?

https://x.com/XDevelopers/status/1621026986784337922 Starting February 9, we will no longer support free access to the Twitter API, both v2 and v1.1. A paid basic tier will be available instead

if i upgrade to basic access can i use the get trends endpoint ? or do i have to be on the pro ?
